# amazon_scraper installation issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, installation, amazon-product-api

This is the link from where i am trying to download the scraper:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amazon_scraper/0.1.2

After trying the command ( pip install amazon_scraper) i get this error :

```
pip install amazon_scraper
Collecting amazon-scraper
  Using cached amazon_scraper-0.3.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "c:\users\saurin\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jxcqui\amazon-scraper\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        del os.link
    AttributeError: link
```

> [31mCommand "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   c:\users\saurin\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-jxcqui\amazon-scraper[0m

I tried downloading the rar file running the setup file. I am getting various issues, does any one have solution to this ?

Comment: Please add information about what platform (eg python version, OS version etc) you are on.

Comment: Currently using Python 2.7.10

Comment: And OS version is : Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have all the require dependencies installed.

- python-amazon-simple-product-api
- requests
- beautifulsoup4
- xmltodict
- python-dateutil

Comment: Not sure about windows as I am linux user, but shouldn't pip handle these automatically?

Comment: Don't believe so, you can install them in your project or globally if you have it in your path. Also need to check what version of python your running vs the library python version supports.

Comment: I did make sure to install all the dependencies, Using Python 2.7 and Windows 10. Would this work on linux ?

Comment: Try it? Also are you sure that you have install the correct setup tools for python? `egg_info` can suggest they aren't. Found this link on another post to run https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

Comment: @saurinshah no worries, if answer correct please mark so question is closed.